# Accuracy not increasing with BERT Large model

Tags: nlp, pytorch, bert-language-model

I used both `BERT_base_cased` and `BERT_large_Cased` model for multi class text classification. With BERT_base_cased, I got satisfactory results. When I tried with BERT_large_cased model, the accuracy is same for all the epochs

[image]

[image]

With `BERT_base_cased`, there is no such problem. But with `BERT_large_cased`, why accuracy is same in all the epochs? Any help is really appreciated.............

Comment: What is the number of samples that you are using for training?

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa          I experimented with BERT large on two datasets. The sizes of data sets are 6500, 2300.

Comment: It is too low for BERT, which is a huge model even in the case of BERT-BASE

Comment: Is small size of data set is the only reason for this kind of behavior?

Comment: In this paper, (https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1908/1908.03548.pdf), the authors successfully experimented with BERT large on three data sets  with training sets of sizes 5816, 5921 and 7038.

Comment: Well, accuracy not improving may also be due to other factors, but for sure size of the dataset is a major influence.

Comment: In this paper, (arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1908/1908.03548.pdf), the authors successfully experimented with BERT_Large on three data sets with training sets of sizes 5816, 5921 and 7038.